# Correct Way To "COUNTUNIQUE" That Only Counts Once

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to count the unique values of a column, based on their status in another column, example:

| Customers | License Active |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | Yes |
| Barry | No |
| Adam | No |
| Claire | No |

In this situation, I want to know how many customers have at least 1 active license, and how many customers do **not** have at least one active license.

The formula I have tried is:
`=COUNTUNIQUEIFS(A2:A,B2:B,"Yes")`
This returns `1` in this situation which is correct, as there is 1 customer who has a Yes on column B.
My issue is when I try to do the reverse, count the "No" using this formula:
`=COUNTUNIQUEIFS(A2:A,B2:B,"No")` it returns `3` which is not the desired result as it is counting the second `Adam` as a unique value too because they have a "No" in column B.

The result I want here is `2`, because Adam has a yes somewhere in column B so I don't want him counted again the next time his field is counted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it in a single step - try filtering out those with at least one "Yes" like this:

```
=countunique(filter(A2:A,countifs(B2:B,"Yes",A2:A,A2:A)=0))
```

[image]

---

**Explanation**

When a countifs has a range instead of a single value in its criteria part countifs(B2:B,"Yes",A2:A,**A2:A**) , the countifs gets re-evaluated for each cell in the range. So you get an array with the results of

```
countifs(B2:B,"Yes",A2:A,A2)
countifs(B2:B,"Yes",A2:A,A3)
countifs(B2:B,"Yes",A2:A,A4)
countifs(B2:B,"Yes",A2:A,A5)
```

and so on all the way down the columns.

The first countifs above checks right through a2:a and b2:b to see if there are *any* cases where the name is Adam and the license condition is true and gets a count of 1 so that row is filtered out. The same thing happens in the next row containing Adam (row 4) - the countifs checks right through both columns excluding the headers and the count is still 1 so that row is filtered out as well leaving just Barry and Claire.

If you wanted to exclude all records containing "Test" in the Customer column, You could add a condition to the filter using the multiplication operator to 'AND' it with the existing condition:

```
=countunique(filter(A2:A,(countifs(B2:B,"Yes",A2:A,A2:A)=0)*(A2:A<>"Test")))
```

If you had several names to exclude, you would probably want to make a list of them and use a lookup to stop the formula getting too long and unwieldy, but it would be the same idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom, this worked and as it is a little more robust than Erik's answer above (which also worked fine) I have accepted this as it allows me to continue to the next step of my formula a little easier because it more clearly expresses what I am trying to do. 

If you have a minute, would you mind walking me through how the "filter" with "countifs" works in this case; how is it filtering out ALL instances of an exact match in A:A if any of them have a "Yes" in B:B? I don't quite understand that bit :)

Comment: Tom, a further question if I may: 

Is there any way to filter within the filter to exclude a specific record from the count? For example if there was a record in A:A that was "Test" that had multiple rows assigned to it. 

Is there any way to add that to the filter so it only "countunique"'s excluding any cells in A:A that are "Test"

Comment: Yes of course, am just going out  but will have a look later.

Comment: Explanation added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the easiest way to get the "No" count is like this:

`=COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A)-COUNTUNIQUEIFS(A2:A,B2:B,"Yes")`

It's even easier if you've already pulled the "Yes" count to a cell (say, C2), in which case the "No" count could be gained quite simply with this:

`=COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A)-C2`

Comment: Thanks Erik, this worked and is the simplest solution. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. And you're also getting to see here that there are many ways to achieve the same goal in Sheets.